# How do onion services host anonymous chatrooms and what level of anonymity is present when using one?

Tags: onion-services, anonymity, security, deanonymization, chat

There are many onion services such as Talk to John Doe and OnionChat which have anonymous chatrooms. How do they connect random users and let them chat with each other. How anonymous are users when they use these chatrooms (I know this depends on each individual website, but is there some anonymity taken when using such services in general)? Also, what are some ways I can tell if these chatrooms are or aren't that secure and private (HTTPS websites hosting chatrooms are encrypted and thus more private right)?